# React native app to react native web problem (typescript, babel)

Tags: react-native

Hello so I'm working on an app for android and iOS which is quite developed by now and I'd like to activate react-native-web on it. the problem is that I have a bug when I try to run the script to launch the web development server :
[image: bug]

The first error at the top is the one I'm struggling with I've tried updating my babel config :

[image: babel-config]

I tried deleting the babel config at the root of my project and it changed nothing like the babel config has no importance

It is being used though to build the android app i know that, but for the react native web build it seems he has no importance

But is still get the same error again and again

please let me know if you need any more information's on this issue